# Couple performance questions (one bigger vector vs smaller chunks vectors) and Is it worth to store iteration index for jump access of vector?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am a bit curiuous about vector optimization and have couple questions about it. (I am still a beginner in programing)

example:

```
struct GameInfo{
    EnumType InfoType;
    // Other info...
};

int _lastPosition;
// _gameInfoV is sorted beforehand
std::vector<GameInfo> _gameInfoV;

// The tick function is called every game frame (in "perfect" condition it's every 1.0/60 second)
void BaseClass::tick()
{
    for (unsigned int i = _lastPosition; i < _gameInfoV.size(); i++{
        auto & info = _gameInfoV[i];
        if( !info.bhasbeenAdded ){
            if( DoWeNeedNow() ){
            _lastPosition++;
            info.bhasbeenAdded = true;
            _otherPointer->DoSomething(info.InfoType);
            // Do something more with "info"....
            }
            else return;  //Break the cycle since we don't need now other "info"
        }
    }
}
```

The `_gameInfoV` vector size can be between `2000` and `5000`.

My main 2 questions are:

1. Is it better to leave the way how it is or it's better to make smaller chunks of it, which is checked for every different `GameInfo.InfoType`
2. Is it worth the hassle of storing the last start position index of the vector instead of iterating from the beginning.

Note that if using smaller vectors there will be like `3 to 6` of them

The third thing is probably that I am not using vector iterators, but is it safe to use then like this?

```
std::vector<GameInfo>::iterator it = _gameInfoV.begin() + _lastPosition;
for (it = _gameInfoV.begin(); it != _gameInfoV.end(); ++it){
    //Do something
}
```

Note: It will be used in smartphones, so every optimization will be appreciated, when targeting weaker phones.

-Thank you

Comment: I recommend posting to CodeReview@StackExchange.com, if your program is working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't; except if you frequently move memory around
2. It is no hassle if you do it correctly:

   ```
   std::vector<GameInfo>::const_iterator _lastPosition(gameInfoV.begin());
   // ...
   for (std::vector<GameInfo>::iterator info=_lastPosition; it!=_gameInfoV.end(); ++info)
   {
       if (!info->bhasbeenAdded)
       {
           if (DoWeNeedNow())
           {
               ++_lastPosition;
               _otherPointer->DoSomething(info->InfoType);
               // Do something more with "info"....
           }
           else return;  //Break the cycle since we don't need now other "i
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: "except if you frequently move memory around" - Could you please give me an a example of how "frequently" should be to count it as "worth doing smaller vector"?

Comment: Also does it means that in the cycle I will not be allowed to modify info->bhasbeenAdded ,due to I am using then "const_iterator" ?

Answer (score 0):

Breaking one vector up into several smaller vectors in general doesn't improve performance.  It could even slightly degrade performance because the compiler has to manage more variables, which take up more CPU registers etc.

I don't know about gaming so I don't understand the implication of GameInfo.InfoType.  Your processing time and CPU resource requirements are going to increase if you do more total iterations through loops (where each loop iteration performs the same type of operation).  So if separating the vectors causes you to avoid some loop iterations because you can skip entire vectors, that's going to increase performance of your app.

iterators are the most secure way to iterate through containers.  But for a vector I often just use the index operator [] and my own indexer (a plain old unsigned integer).

Comment: The InfoType is just enum which is like : STATIC_OBSTACLE, DYNAMIC_OBSTACLE, LOW_GROUND_PLATFROM and etc..So it allow for me to know where and when to place them and how to initialize them.